# Pick fields from ndarray with serde-json

Tags: rust, serde

I have a struct containing data that's either a float or a one-dim ndarray:

```
#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct Results {
    pub data: Data,

}

#[derive(Serialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum Data {
    Float(f32),
    Array1(ndarray::Array1<f32>),
}
```

When serializing Array1 with serde-json I want to discard the "v" and "dim" keys from ndarray and flatten the "data" key so the structure looks like this:

```
"{\"data\":[1.0,2.0,3.0]}"
```

How would you do that?

Comment: What have you tried?  It sounds like you'll need to `impl Serialize` yourself instead of `derive`.

Comment: I was hoping I could use something "out-of-the-box" like pick fields and flatten but couldnt find it in the docs, so you are probably right...